# Enterprise Shared Library Management - Best Practice

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

In general i would like to know your ideas/best practice of managing shared libraries across multiple projects.

I've got one shared lib that is used within lots of c# projects maintained with visual studio how do i get an overview about the lib usage.

I've got the following ideas:
1) Within the shared lib VS project map add all projects using the lib
Pro: easy to see the usage and redeployment
Con: confusing if there are lots of projects using the lib

2) Use some manage tool?
   - are there special tools? - use Excel? :-(

3) Use a script that copies that lib into each project using that lib
   ->sub-problem: start redeployment of that projects (projects are heterogeneous distributed  some with script some with one-click deploy)

other ideas?

I think nothing suits well the general problem of knowing which projects use a lib.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We tend to use a folder to stored shared assemblies in, these are simply stored in TFS and referenced from that location.